# MongoDB combining $and and $or

Tags: mongodb

```
select * 
from job 
where 
    (title LIKE %xxx% OR dsc LIKE %xxx% OR requirements LIKE %xxx% ) 
    AND 
    (country LIKE %xxx%)
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?

Comment: Is your example SQL? You should edit your post to say what it is. Also what have you tried and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
db.job.find({
    $and : [
        {$or : [
            {title  : \xxx\},
            {dsc : \xxx\},
            {requirements : \xxx\}
        ]},
        {country : \xxx\}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks  Mohsen it worked...Yes my example was SQL.. Needed MongoDB query help.